Inconsistent tabs and indentation while doing a "while true" function
def getprompt(ser, addr, verbose, shell):
    # Send a command who does not produce a result so when receiving the next line feed, only show the prompt will be returned
    # Flushing read buffer
if not shell:
    buf = ""
        while True:
        oldbuf = buf
        buf = ser.read(256);
        combined = oldbuf+buf
        if "machid: 8010001" in combined:
            ser.write("xyzzy");
                    while ser.read(256):
                           pass
            break

    if verbose:
            print("Waiting for a prompt...")
    while True:
            # Write carriage return and wait for a response
            ser.write(LINE_FEED)
            # Read the response
            buf = ser.read(256);
            if (buf.endswith(b"> ") or buf.endswith(b"# ")):
                    print("Prompt is '" + buf[2:] + "'")
                    # The prompt returned starts with a line feed. This is the echo of the line feed we send to get the prompt.
                    # We keep this linefeed
                    return buf
            else:
                    # Flush read buffer
                    while True:
            buf = ser.read(256)
            if (buf.endswith(b"> ") or buf.endswith(b"# ")):
                            print("Prompt is '" + buf[2:] + "'")
                            # The prompt returned starts with a line feed. This is the echo of the line feed we send to get the prompt.
                            # We keep this linefeed
                            return buf
                            pass

There is this tutorial that I was following:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jJa8LzYnY830v3nBZdOgAk0YQK6OdbSS 
that uses the file "wbootwrite.py" inside the folder, and when I run it on my raspberry pi, it throws that error 
File "/home/user/mr30h/MR33/ubootwrite/./ubootwrite.py", line 34
    while True:
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

How do I fix that?

The cause has nothing to do with Python; you need to configure your editor to insert spaces instead of actual tab characters, either during autoindentation or when you press the physical Tab key.
